# Not finding routing for home module

Tags: angular, module

I create a standard angular app then add a home module then add a home component but the page is always displaying a  blank page.

To create the application:

1. ng new angularapp
2. ng g m modules\home
3. ng g c modules\home\home
4. Add a home-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

Alter the home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';

// Routing for the module
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: []
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Alter the app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Application Modules
import { HomeModule } from './modules/home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // Angular
    BrowserModule,
    // app
    AppRoutingModule,
    // Application Modules
    HomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Alter the app.component.html

```
Angular Application
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Run the app:

```
ng serve -o
```

And I get on the header with angular application

Any help would be grateful

NOTE: Git Repo - https://github.com/scossgrove/AngularModules

Comment: Have you try my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think every thing is fine in your code except you are not exporting the **`HomeComponent`** in the **`Home Module`**. That's why you are unable show anything on the browser.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
   HomeComponent   // add your component here
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: []
})

export class HomeModule { }
```

hope this will solve your issue.. :)

Comment: Changed it to be in the export but still don't have the home.component.html showing

Answer (score 0):

```
//app.module.ts
imports:[
  RouterModule.forRoot([])   
] 

//app-routing.module.ts
 {
   path: '', 
   loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
                 //(path with file name of homeModule # exported class in home.module.ts)
  }
```

Add above code in app.module.ts &app-routing.module.ts file

Comment: Pretty sure not related to lazy load

Comment: change to the follow:

const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

but still nothing

Comment: Have you import  RouterModule.forRoot([]) in app.module.ts file

Comment: @TonyNgo it is lazy loading

Comment: I know but the issue is not related to lazy load :)

Answer (score 0):

in case you are wondering...
The answer is the order in which I was importing in the app.modules.ts.

I needed to change it to the following:

```
imports: [
    // Angular
    BrowserModule,
    // Application Modules
    HomeModule,
    // app
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

And it worked.